# Google Calendar API - Recurring Events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API to retrieve my calendar entries. All appears to work as my entries are coming through.

But, I have noticed a problem with events that are recurring.

These are my parameter options

```
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 50,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => date('c')            
    );

    $service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
```

With the above code I am missing an event.
If I use the parameters below, the event comes through, but with a date of 4th Feb 2020 (earlier than timeMin)

```
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 50,
        //'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        //'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => date('c')
    );
```

This is a recurring event which possibly had the original date of 4 Feb 2020. The event is not showing on my actual Google Calendar on 4th Feb - deleted.

I must be doing something incorrectly. Can anyone shed some light please.

Comment: The first method do return recurring events instances. How did you deleted the original event?

Comment: Not exactly sure how it was deleted. I am not the only person part of the event - but it is not showing on my calendar. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with other recurring events? Or you cannot see any recurring event with the `events->listEvents()` method?

Comment: Other recurring events are coming through. Perhaps it is an anomimily. Just a bit concerned if it happens again, we may miss things. I will keep my eye on it. Thanks for your help.